# Cálculo de comissão de vendedor javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e preciso calcular a comissão. Exemplo:  (ao digitar o valor total do cerviço tem que dar resultado de custo de serviço no segundo input e no terceiro input o valor que o cliente ira receber, no codigo abaixo consegui calcular o custo de servico, mas nao consigo calcular o valor que o cliente vai receber,) como eu poderia fazer isso em javascript ?

exemplo
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHHzn.png

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>cálculo</title >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
         function calcular() {
        var comissao = (parseFloat($("#valorPorcentagem").val())/100) * parseFloat($("#valor_vendedor").val());
        $("#comissao").val(comissao);
      }
    </script>
   
      <div>
        <h2>Orçamento</h2>
        
      <input value="20"  id="valorPorcentagem" hidden>
      <span>Valor total:</span>
      <input id="valor_vendedor" onkeyup="calcular()">
      <br>
      <br><span>Custo de serviço:</span>
      
      <input type="text" name="custo" id="comissao" readonly>
      <br>
      <br>
        <span>O que voce receberá</span>
      <input type="text" name="pago"  id="sera_pago" readonly>

      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calcular() {
    var comissao = (parseFloat($("#valorPorcentagem").val()) / 100) * parseFloat($("#valor_vendedor").val());
    $("#comissao").val(comissao);
    $("#sera_pago").val($("#valor_vendedor").val() - $("#comissao").val())
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Calculos</title>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h2>Orçamento</h2>
         <input value="20"  id="valorPorcentagem" hidden>
         <span>Valor total:</span>
         <input id="valor_vendedor" onkeyup="calcular()">
         <br>
         <br><span>Custo de serviço:</span>
         <input type="text" name="custo" id="comissao" readonly>
         <br>
         <br>
         <span>O que voce receberá</span>
         <input type="text" name="pago"  id="sera_pago" readonly>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade do _listener_ no script se já tem um no HTML?

Comment: Bem observado. Fiz o ajuste. Obrigado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rodrigo, você me ajudou muito